Custom Loss function Cannot squeeze axis=-1
I'm working on implementing a custom loss function in TensorFlow/Keras that incorporates both categorical cross-entropy loss and a penalty based on custom rules. These rules are designed to penalize predictions that fall outside certain boundaries for specific features.
For more context: each sample is composed by 6 components (3 for Accelerometer, 3 for Gyroscope) and used that data do define some boundaries in which some new derived data (like mean, standard deviation...) resides. Using these boundaries, I wanted to penalize a prediction if the sample was too far away from the rules values, hopefully increasing accuracy. But I have been getting a lot of errors, and this one I cannot really understand.
If you have any additional tips on the custom loss, I would be happy to hear them since it's my first time working with a custom one.
expanded_labels = np.tile(y_train_cstm.reshape(-1, 1, 1), (1, x_train_cstm.shape[1], 1))

# Concatenate the labels as a new column in the last axis
padded_data = np.concatenate([x_train_cstm, expanded_labels], axis=2)

class CustomLoss(Loss):
    def __init__(self, rules, num_classes, verbose=False):
        super(CustomLoss, self).__init__()
        self.rules = rules
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.verbose = verbose

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        return custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, self.rules, self.num_classes, self.verbose)

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, rules, num_classes, verbose=False):
    # Extract features and labels
    x_train = y_true[:, :, :-1]  
    y_train_labels = y_true[:, 0, -1] 

    # One-hot encode the labels
    y_train_labels_one_hot = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(y_train_labels, tf.int32), depth=num_classes)

    # Check and handle shape mismatch between y_true and y_pred
    if y_train_labels_one_hot.shape != y_pred.shape:
        y_train_labels_one_hot = tf.reshape(y_train_labels_one_hot, tf.shape(y_pred))

    # Handle undefined tensors (e.g., NaN or Inf values)
    y_pred = tf.where(tf.math.is_finite(y_pred), y_pred, tf.zeros_like(y_pred))
    y_train_labels_one_hot = tf.where(tf.math.is_finite(y_train_labels_one_hot), y_train_labels_one_hot, tf.zeros_like(y_train_labels_one_hot))
    
    print(f"{y_pred.shape=} {y_train_labels_one_hot.shape=}")

    # Initialize the categorical cross-entropy loss
    cce_loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()(y_train_labels_one_hot, y_pred)

    # Initialize rule penalty
    rule_penalty = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32)

    def compute_rule_penalty(sample, label):
        penalty = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32)

        # Use tf.py_function to iterate over rules
        def rule_penalty_pyfunc(sample, label):
            nonlocal penalty
            for rule in rules:
                if rule.cid == tf.argmax(label):  # Check if the rule applies to this class
                    for j in range(sample.shape[0]):
                        feature_value = sample[j, rule.feat].numpy()  # Extract the relevant feature value

                        # Calculate the distance from the rule boundaries
                        distance = 0.0
                        if feature_value < rule.lb:
                            distance = rule.lb - feature_value
                        elif feature_value > rule.rb:
                            distance = feature_value - rule.rb

                        # Add penalty proportional to the distance
                        penalty += distance * rule.reward(feature_value)
            return penalty

        # Call the Python function via tf.py_function
        penalty = tf.py_function(rule_penalty_pyfunc, [sample, label], tf.float32)
        return penalty

    # Apply the rule penalty function across the batch
    penalties = tf.map_fn(lambda x: compute_rule_penalty(x[0], x[1]), (x_train, y_train_labels_one_hot), dtype=tf.float32)
    rule_penalty = tf.reduce_sum(penalties)

    # Combine the CCE loss and the rule penalty
    total_loss = cce_loss + rule_penalty

    if verbose:
        tf.print("Loss:", cce_loss)
        tf.print("Rule Penalty:", rule_penalty)
        tf.print("Total Loss:", total_loss)

    return total_loss

input_shape_cstm = x_data_cstm.shape[1:]

model_type = 'conv1d_lstm'
model = make_model(model_type, input_shape_cstm, len(CLASSES))

# Use the custom loss with verbose=True

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=CustomLoss(rules=rules, num_classes= len(CLASSES), verbose=True), metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(x_train, padded_data, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

The error:
Making conv1d_lstm model with input shape (50, 6), hidden 64, 128, out classes 8
Epoch 1/10
y_pred.shape=TensorShape([None, 8]) y_train_labels_one_hot.shape=TensorShape([None, 8])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-323-127b82319b96> in <cell line: 11>()
      9 
     10 # Train the model
---> 11 model.fit(x_train, padded_data, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120             # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121             # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123         finally:
    124             del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/numpy.py in squeeze(x, axis)
   2303         for a in axis:
   2304             if static_shape[a] != 1:
-> 2305                 raise ValueError(
   2306                     f"Cannot squeeze axis={a}, because the "
   2307                     "dimension is not 1."

ValueError: Cannot squeeze axis=-1, because the dimension is not 1.

